# Why this property of VC(a)<VC(b) ==> a->b of Vector Clocks always holds?

Tags: computer-science, distributed-computing, distributed-system, vector-clock

According to Wikipedia page of Vector Clocks:

```
If VC(a) < VC(b) then a -> b

    VC - Vecor Clock
    -> - casually related
```

But if we have the following schema: 
[Click Here For the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glggC.jpg)

Now we can see the event with VC(1,0,1) and VC(0,2,2), they fullfill the condition:

```
sqrt(1+0+1) < sqrt(0+4+4) =>  sqrt(2) < sqrt(8)    //TRUE
```

But these two events (VC(1,0,1) and VC(0,2,2)) are not in the casual order relation!

Could someone tell me what is wrong here, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the event here!

If actor x has a vector clock VC(x) = VC(1, 0, 1) and actor y has vector clock VC(y) = VC(0, 2, 2) then. 
- There is an event that actor x knows that y is not aware of (or causality dependent on). This event happened when the first value of the clock changed from 0 to 1.
- Also, there are three events that y know and x is not aware of (or causality dependent on). These events happened when the second and third values incremented on the vector clock.  So:

VC(x) is not <= VC(y)
VC(y) is not <= VC(x)

These clock don't have causal dependency and can't be compared directly.